# Wifi connection problem with Atheros AR9485 problem

Tags: 13.04, wireless, atheros

I'm currently working in 13.04. The network manager indicates that the WIFI is always connected. However, the Internet connection only last a few seconds and then it disconnects. The problem only exist when I want to connect to a WPA2-Enterprise protected network. There is not problem if I connect another unprotected network.

I have tried the nohwcrypt=1 method, but it does not help.

What can be the problem? Let me know if you need any further information.

Thanks

Comment: Open a terminal and enter `lspci | grep WiFi`. Post the result as edit.

Comment: @the_Seppi Thanks, but the result is empty. But the last line, if I type lspci, is `04:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)`

Comment: Did you install a proprietary diver or do you use the preinstalled one?

Comment: @the_Seppi I did not install any drivers. I have just installed ubuntu for a few minutes. So I think I am using the preinstalled one.

Comment: Then check whether Atheros provides any Linux drivers for your card.

Comment: @the_Seppi I think the ath9k is the general driver for Atheros products. There should not be any update.